# ICount how many words are in a string

Tags: python, string, split, cpu-word

I am not talking about how many times it says a specific word or letter, but how many words there are in a string.

here is the code so far:

```
list = []
x = raw_input("Text: ")
x.split()

abc = x.split(" ")
list.append(abc)
print list.count(",")#here i tried to count how many time "," shows up
#and have it where if it says 1 time then their is two, three times then
#there is 4 words, but it does not work and Would not be accurate if i typed "hello, again"
```

How can i count how many words are in the string? Thank you

Comment: Won't `x.count(' ')+1` help? Or `len(x.split())` for tab and newline.

Comment: why not just `len(abc)`?

Comment: `list` is a) a bad name to use (it shadows a builtin name and it isn't descriptive) and b) not helpful for you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these ways can help:

```
x = raw_input("Text: ")
print len(x.split())
```

Or:

```
import re
x = raw_input("Text: ")
r=re.compile(r"\b")
print len(re.findall(r,x))/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Determining what constitutes a word is actually a rather tricky problem, but if you just mean things that there are spaces between, that's not so hard.

```
list = []
x = raw_input("Text: ")
x.split()

abc = x.split(" ") # print out or otherwise view `abc` -- 
list.append(abc) # I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here -- this 
                 # puts your list `abc` in your list `list`.
print list.count(",") # I'm not sure why you think `list` would have "," in it 
                      # list has only one thing in it -- another list (abc)
```

Maybe it will help to look at an example.

```
>>> list = [] # DON'T CALL IT 'list', give it a different name
>>> x = raw_input("Text: ")
Text: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
>>> x
'Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.'
>>> abc = x.split()
>>> abc
['Now', 'is', 'the', 'time', 'for', 'all', 'good', 'men', 'to', 'come', 'to', 'the', 'aid', 'of', 'their', 'country.']
>>> list.append(abc)
>>> list
[['Now', 'is', 'the', 'time', 'for', 'all', 'good', 'men', 'to', 'come', 'to', 'the', 'aid', 'of', 'their', 'country.']]
>>> list[0]
['Now', 'is', 'the', 'time', 'for', 'all', 'good', 'men', 'to', 'come', 'to', 'the', 'aid', 'of', 'their', 'country.']
>>> list[0][0]
'Now'
```